# Longest palindrome in a string?

Tags: c++, string, function, class, palindrome

I want to print the longest palindrome in a string , I have written the code but this is giving wrong answer for some test cases . I am not able to find the error in my code .
Anyone help me with this , Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Input

```
vnrtysfrzrmzlygfv
```

Output

```
v
```

Expected output

```
rzr
```

Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int ispalindrome(string s)
    {
        string rev = "";
        int n = s.size();
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            rev = rev + s[i];
        }
        if (rev == s) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    string longestPalin(string S)
    {
        // code here
        int size = S.size();
        int size_of_substr = 0;
        string ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                string s2 = S.substr(i, j);
                if (ispalindrome(s2)) {
                    if (s2.size() > size_of_substr) {
                        ans = s2;
                        size_of_substr = s2.size();
                    }
                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question. Also add a main, so others can compile and run the code. In short, please post a [mcve]

Comment: It seems you are using `substr` incorrectly. The second argument is the size of the substring. See [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). Moreover, this code will not be very efficient ...

Comment: Looks like this is a [problem from letcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/). `Solution` class is usually used there to encapsulate user code.

Comment: indeed it looks like leetcode. For debugging and to run your own tests you should add a `main` instead of only relying on the online judge. A debugger and detailed test can tell much more than just "passed" or "not passed"

Comment: `main` is not best choice it is better to provide a test: https://godbolt.org/z/xqcadG3fa (here code from Damiens answer is used, with `O(N^3)` time complexity). With leetcode link it is easy to create such test. It is possible to have much faster solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `substr(.)` incorrectly. The second argument is the size of the substring.

`string s2 = S.substr(i, j);` should be replaced by `string s2 = S.substr(i, j-i+1);`

Moreover, this code will not be very efficient. To speed it up, I modified your code in the following way:

1. I pass the string by reference to the `ispalindrome`function
2. I modified the algorithm to check if the substring is a palindrome. It returns `false` after the first mismatch
3. I don't build each substring explicitly. I only pass the start and beginning of the substring to the helper function
4. I start by checking if there exists a palindrome of the maximum size, and then I decrease its length. As soon as a palindrome is found, we know it has the maximum size, and we can stop the search

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Solution {
public:
    int ispalindrome(const std::string& S, int i, int j) {
        while (i < j) {
            if (S[i++] != S[j--]) return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    std::string longestPalindrome(const std::string& S) {
        int size = S.size();
        int imax = 1;
        for (int size_of_substr = size; size_of_substr > 0; size_of_substr--, imax++) {
            int j = size_of_substr - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++, j++) {
                if (ispalindrome(S, i, j)) {
                        std::string ans = S.substr(i, size_of_substr);
                        return ans;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution sol;
    std::string S;
    std::cin >> S;
    auto ans = sol.longestPalindrome(S);
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `size_of_substr` is the size of the substring, and if `i` is the index of the start of the substring, then we have `i + size_of_substr < size + 1` then `i < imax = size - size_of_substr + 1`.